# Is there a way to give a device LAN access but not internet access?

Tags: router, lan

I have a WiFi device that I want to be able to connect to other machines on my network, but not to the Internet. I have an ASUS RT-N56U Router. I have looked through the router settings and searched the internet but haven't found an answer. Any ideas?

Edit1: I found this:
[image]

Comment: does your firewall allow egress filtering?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'll check when I get home from work

Comment: I would also look for access restrictions or parental controls which could be used to restrict access.

Comment: Check out Edit1. So Source would be the device's IP. Port range would probably be 0-65535 for both. Might have to make a TCP _and_ UDP rule. Should that work?

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the restricted device manually, without configuring a default route/gateway, or setting it to 127.0.0.1, it will allow the device to communicate on the LAN only.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean here?

Comment: I don't really know how to...  Have you attempted to configure that device manually?

Comment: I have, but I do not trust the device. That is why I want to do it via the router.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible for you to set the device up with a static IP without a gateway address? This would solve your problem immediately. Everything and anything would be reachable on the local network, but the device wouldn't know how to reach anything on the internet.